# List of Python library in Sagemaker SKlearnProcessor

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Is there a way to list the Python library in Sagemaker SKlearnProcessor?
Could not find the list from official doc. ,
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_processing.html#data-pre-processing-and-model-evaluation-with-scikit-learn

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find the list of installed packages.

To work around this issue, you can refer to the [GitHub example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker_processing/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation/scikit_learn_data_processing_and_model_evaluation.ipynb) and make modifications to the `preprocessing.py` file to print the list of installed libraries. One approach is to utilize the command `os.system('pip freeze')` and then inspect the CloudWatch logs for the respective job.

I've tested this with the `sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.20.0-cpu-py3` environment, and below is the complete list of installed packages:

```
bcrypt==3.2.0
boto3==1.17.36
botocore==1.20.36
brotlipy==0.7.0
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cffi_1613246939562/work
chardet @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/chardet_1607706768982/work
click==7.1.2
conda==4.9.2
conda-package-handling @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/conda-package-handling_1603018138503/work
cryptography @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cryptography_1615530759576/work
Flask==1.1.1
gevent==21.1.2
greenlet==1.0.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna @ file:///home/linux1/recipes/ci/idna_1610986105248/work
inotify-simple==1.2.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jmespath==0.10.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mlio==0.1.3
numpy==1.20.1
pandas==0.25.3
paramiko==2.7.2
protobuf==3.15.6
psutil==5.8.0
pyarrow==0.14.1
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1594388511720/work
PyNaCl==1.4.0
pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1608057966937/work
PySocks @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pysocks_1594394576006/work
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pytz_1612179539967/work
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1608241421344/work
retrying==1.3.3
ruamel-yaml-conda @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ruamel_yaml_1616016701961/work
s3transfer==0.3.6
sagemaker-containers==2.8.6.post2
sagemaker-sklearn-container @ file:///sagemaker_sklearn_container-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sagemaker-training==3.7.3
scikit-learn==0.20.0
scipy==1.6.2
six @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/six_1605205313296/work
tqdm @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1615925068909/work
typing==3.7.4.3
urllib3 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/urllib3_1615837158687/work
Werkzeug==1.0.1
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.3.0
```

Additionally, you can install extra libraries using the command `os.system('pip install ...')`.

Update 1/11/2023: The list of installed packages during container build can be found in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container/blob/master/requirements.txt) file, but it may not include the entire list.